# How to write to a varchar(max) column using ODBC

Tags: c++, sql-server, sql-server-2005, odbc

Summary: I'm trying to write a text string to a column of type varchar(max) using ODBC and SQL Server 2005. It fails if the length of the string is greater than 8000. Help!

I have some C++ code that uses ODBC (SQL Native Client) to write a text string to a table. If I change the column from, say, varchar(100) to varchar(max) and try to write a string with length greater than 8000, the write fails with the following error

> [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server
>   Driver]String data, right truncation

So, can anyone advise me on if this can be done, and how?

Some example (*not* production) code that shows what I'm trying to do:

```
SQLHENV hEnv = NULL;
SQLRETURN iError = SQLAllocEnv(&hEnv);

HDBC hDbc = NULL;
SQLAllocConnect(hEnv, &hDbc);

const char* pszConnStr = "Driver={SQL Server};Server=127.0.0.1;Database=MyTestDB";
UCHAR szConnectOut[SQL_MAX_MESSAGE_LENGTH];
SWORD iConnectOutLen = 0;
iError = SQLDriverConnect(hDbc, NULL, (unsigned char*)pszConnStr,
                      SQL_NTS, szConnectOut,
                      (SQL_MAX_MESSAGE_LENGTH-1), &iConnectOutLen,
                      SQL_DRIVER_COMPLETE);

HSTMT hStmt = NULL;
iError = SQLAllocStmt(hDbc, &hStmt);

const char* pszSQL = "INSERT INTO MyTestTable (LongStr) VALUES (?)";
iError = SQLPrepare(hStmt, (SQLCHAR*)pszSQL, SQL_NTS);

char* pszBigString = AllocBigString(8001);
iError = SQLSetParam(hStmt, 1, SQL_C_CHAR, SQL_VARCHAR, 0, 0, (SQLPOINTER)pszBigString, NULL);

iError = SQLExecute(hStmt);  // Returns SQL_ERROR if pszBigString len > 8000
```

The table MyTestTable contains a single colum defined as varchar(max). The function AllocBigString (not shown) creates a string of arbitrary length.

I understand that previous versions of SQL Server had an 8000 character limit to varchars, but not why is this happening in SQL 2005?

Thanks,
Andy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You sure you load the SQL Native Driver for 2005, not the old driver for 2000? The native driver name is [{SQL Server Native Client 10.0}](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms130822.aspx) for 2k8 or [{SQL Native Client}](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms130822(SQL.90).aspx) for 2k5

The error message `ODBC SQL Server Driver` seem to indicate the old 2k driver (I may be wrong, haven't touch ODBC in like 10 years now).

Comment: Thank you Remus! You were right, I was using the wrong driver. When I changed that, it worked.

For the record, I used the following connection string:

    Driver={SQL Native Client}; Server=127.0.0.1; Database=MyTestDB;

which is not quite the same as the driver name you gave, but your sugestion pointed me to the answer.

Thanks again - much appreciated.

Andy

Comment: Apparently I can't surpass the challenge of copy paste a name from MSDN to an answer lol. Right, the name is {SQL Native Client}, I'll fix my post too, for other google sake.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that although the fix works for SQLSetParam, it does not work for SQLBindParameter.

For example:

```
int iLength = 18001;
char* pszBigString = new char[iLength + 1];
memset(pszBigString, 'a', iLength);
pszBigString[iLength] = 0;
LONG_PTR lLength = SQL_NTS;
::SQLBindParameter(hStmt, 1, SQL_PARAM_INPUT,
                SQL_C_CHAR,
                SQL_VARCHAR,
                iLength, 0, pszBigString, iLength * sizeof(TCHAR),
                &lLength);
```

will result in the same 22001 "String data, right truncation" error, regardless of which driver is used.

In fact, my experiments have shown that you do **not** actually need to install version 10 of the client driver. Instead you should use SQL_LONGVARCHAR instead of SQL_VARCHAR if you expect the lengths of your strings to exceed 8000 characters. You could potentially perform a mass find-and-replace, but it's possible that using SQL_LONGVARCHAR might incur some sort of penalty (although that's pure speculation; it's an 'extended datatype').

I have tested this successfully with both drivers on Windows XP:

- {SQL Server} 2000.85.1117.00 (04/08/2004)
- {SQL Server Native Client 10.0} 2007.100.1600.22 (10/07/2008)